# Combining monte carlo with deep learning to improve the estimation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo

I am in situation where i need to estimate the attenuation of an EM wave . we consider EM wave as collection of photons. These photons when strike with some dust particles they scatter in different direction and for a random path before colliding with next particle.
We can estimate the attenuation using monte carlo simulations. I want to ask can applying the deep learning here can improve the estimation of attenuation ?

Comment: Hi @user7341333, welcome to the site. Your question sounds more like a line of research than an actual technical question. In any case, you can look into automatic differentiation variational inference (ADVI), which may help you. [PyMC](https://www.pymc.io/projects/examples/en/latest/variational_inference/variational_api_quickstart.html) is a Python framework than can do ADVI.

Comment: Also, you could add more detail about how exactly you use monte carlo simulations to address the problem.

Comment: Monte Carlo would simulate 10^6 photons then take the ratio of those particles that are not absorbed to calculate the transmittance

Comment: I was asking about how you "simulate" those photons, i.e. can you express this simulation as a differentiable expression with some stochastic noise sources? Also, please don't add the details as comments; instead, edit your question.

Comment: @noe i have edited the question

Comment: I am no expert but your problem looks like it would be suitable for ADVI. Check [this snippet created with chatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/share/4b0093cd-5a35-420f-a1bc-852d2ce5583c) for an idea on how to approach it. Also, the snippet is using PyMC3, and you may want to use the current version, so check the [migration docs](https://www.pymc-labs.com/blog-posts/the-quickest-migration-guide-ever-from-pymc3-to-pymc-v40/).

Comment: ok i will check it. thanks